# implement periodic table like grid layout in iphone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, layout, grid, grid-layout

i am just developing some simple app which show the periodic table but my problem is how can i achieve the periodic table like layout in my iPhone app in just landscape format.

i have tried to search some `CustomGridLayout` sdk for IOS but not suitable for me

have goggled the things but not succeeded

following is the reference of periodic table layout which i want to implement

[image]

Comment: UICollectionView ? http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-uicollectionview-tutorial/

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a couple way to do this:

1) You may use `UICollectionView` with custom cell. for this.With cell size equal element cell. But you will hit a several problem here: Some cells should be disabled, and customized in non standard way. In this case section is not useful for you. Overlay button in top on collection view may be difficult to positioning in storyboard.

2) You can use `UIContainerView` with totally custom view and colors. Dynamically added to custom row and column. This ofc have some flaws. Harder to build layout in storyboard (compared to (1) solution), memory management issues.

Comment: I'm inferring from your comments about collection views that you're anticipating that he'd use a standard flow layout. But if you use a custom layout, you just define where the cells go and you don't have to have to worry about empty/disabled cells. Admittedly, given the OPs lack of familiarity with iOS, this is probably too much for him to bite off.